# wpa.conf setup for multiple networks

Tags: wireless, networking, static-ip

I asked this over on the RaspPi forum but figured I'd get a faster response if I posted it here as well.
[WiFi setup for multiple networks - original post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/11631/4191)

Summary:

I have a RaspPi.  Going between home and school. Need static IP for both networks.  I know how to do it if its a single network using WPA.conf.
How do I configure for more than one network and different IP?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [`guessnet`](http://guessnet.alioth.debian.org/). This is a small script which checks in which environment your computer (or RasPi) is and sets its networt settings accordingly. First you have to define some profiles in the script. Later on runs specific tests to see in which network your computer is. Guessnet chooses a profile and changes your network settings.